# Cognito Form with Blackout dates and date functions

Tags: cognito-forms, date

Is there a way to have "blackout" dates on my form?  I rent equipment and when all equipment is rented out, I want  to be able to black out specific dates.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

Although this is currently not a feature, we do have plans to implement this in the future. This will be in the date picker and the validation message that shows under the date picker. You can follow both of these features on our Idea Board, [Custom Validation](https://trello.com/c/uzs1CcgV) and [Date Picker Enhancements](https://trello.com/c/GvLfuE66).